# Canadian citizen employed in the US remotely?

Tags: usa, canada, nafta

I am a Canadian citizen and a Canadian resident. I am currently freelancing and my largest customer, a US public company, is interested in employing me instead of a contract relationship. Is there a way to do is? Again, we are already in an independent contractor relationship, I am very familiar with that, I am interested in the kind where you are on payroll, get benefits etc

Comment: Are you trying to be in the company's payroll while living in Canda? Or are you planing in moving to the US?

Comment: Should we assume that the US company has no subsidiary or other presence in Canada?

Comment: Staying in Canada and no presence of the employee.